# Android default button designers fixed size

Tags: android, user-interface, button

This question might be trivial to some of you.
I am facing a dumb issue working with designers and developers.
According to the designers the android button from material design has a particular style, default button style (top button in the image).
Designer defines a fix height and width 50dp for instance. So they expect to have a button of those dimensions.

But developers when using a default android button, the default button contains margins.
So we use a custom drawable background, in this case the button has the expected dimensions (button a the bottom). But the style is not exactly the same (very few differences, but still). We could try to imitate the default style, but I am not sure it is worth.

So how do you do when working with designers that just use a default button from the material android patterns and expect to have the exact size? 
You consider size with margins? You create a background style? You try to imitate as much as you can the default button? others?

[image]

and this is the simple code used

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_shape"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

tha parameter margin is deferent then hight and width. margin determines the distance from point A to the button.

to et the height and width you can use in your xml file the following code:

example:

```
<Button
android:id = "@id/myButton"
android:layout_width = "50dp"
android:layout_hight = "50dp"
android:text = "test"
android:layout_marginTop = "100dp"
/>
```

the margin top 100dp determines that my button is 100dp from the top of my layout but the width and height determines the button size

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your solution positions the button in an another place, the size of the button is still the same. Designers still see that  the button has less than 50dp.

Comment: The position of the button has to be redefined in the margint_top. If the designers have designed the button with 50 dp and you set height and width to 50 dp then the button must bee the same

Comment: BTW @Manuel_Rodrigues your example contains a typo: you used ":" instead of "=" in the margin property.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `9-patch` for the default button already includes a margin, so visually the button looks smaller than expected. Possible solutions include negative margins or duplicating the default 9-patch and removing the margin, but each option has its own drawbacks.

As @egonzal says, it would be interesting to know other developers solutions when facing the problem.